# Error: paragraph ended before ... was complete

Tags: debugging

I'm quite lost.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\aermb[1]{\def\ae@i@r{#1}\ae@rmb}

\def\ae@rmb{%%
  \typeout{=======> \space\space ae@rmb}%%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
  {\@ae@rmb}{\@ae@rmb[\height]}}

\def\@ae@rmb[#1]{%%
  \typeout{=======> \space @ae@rmb}%%
  \def\ae@i@ht{#1}%%
  \@@ae@rmb}

\def\@@ae@rmb{%%
  \typeout{=======> @@ae@rmb}%%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
  {\typeout{\space\space\space optional arg}\@@@ae@rmb}
  {\typeout{no optional arg}\@@@ae@rmb[\depth]}}

\def\@@@ae@rmb[#1]#2{$#2$}%%

%% \def\@@@ae@rmb[#1]#2{%%
%%   \typeout{-->\detokenize\x{\ae@i@r}}%%
%%   \typeout{-->\detokenize\x{\ae@i@ht}}%%
%%   \typeout{==>\detokenize{#1}}}%%
%%   \raisebox{\ae@i@r}[\ae@i@ht][#1]{\mbox{$#2$}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\aermb{\frac{1}{2}}


\end{document}
```

I get the following error with the above code:

```
=======>   ae@rmb
=======>  @ae@rmb
=======> @@ae@rmb
no optional arg
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@@@ae@rmb was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.30 

?
```

Comment: This is always due to `\par` in the argument of a non `\long` macro.

Comment: @egreg Where is the `\par` coming from?

Comment: @egreg when I add `\long` before `\def\@@@ae@rmb....` I get a new error about missing `$` even though the macro is supposed to insert them.  Why is that?

Comment: From the empty line after `{\frac{1}{2}}`

Comment: @egreg That really confuses me.  I'm sure I've made plenty of macros and used them at the end of a paragraph without such problems.  Why is the paragraph occurring after the macro call effecting the expansion of the macro's argument, which doesn't contain any new paragraph.

Comment: put `x` there and you'll see it is `x` that gets set in math mode not your fraction so it's trying to set `\par`

Comment: I see my error.  I forgot about the argument I gave to `\aermb` when I wrote `\@@@ae@rmb`.

Comment: Should we vote to close or should I just delete this question?

Comment: @A.Ellett I find the question interesting enough. See the `xparse` implementation of your multipronged macro: just a tad easier. `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see what happens.

```
\aermb{\frac{1}{2}}
```

becomes

```
\def\ae@i@r{\frac{1}{2}}\ae@rmb
```

The macro `\ae@rmb` tests if the next token is `[`, skipping spaces. The next token is `\par`, due to the empty line. Thus the input stream, at this point, is

```
\ae@rmb\par
```

and now it becomes

```
\@ae@rmb[\height]\par
```

The macro `\@ae@rmb` does `\def\ae@i@ht{\height}` and the input stream becomes

```
\@@ae@rmb\par
```

Since the next token is not `[`, this becomes

```
\@@@ae@rmb[\depth]\par
```

and now you have the problem, because argument `#2` to `\@@@ae@rmb` is `\par`; this is illegal because the macro is not long. But making it `\long` is not the solution, because `$\par$` is illegal either.

Probably you should define

```
\def\@@@ae@rmb[#1]{%
  something with the saved height,
  with #1 which is the desired depth
  and with \ae@i@r
}
```

---

An easier implementation with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\aermb}{O{\height}O{\depth}m}{%
  \raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}%
  \raisebox{#2}{$#3$}%
  arg: $#3$
}


\begin{document}

1:\aermb{\dfrac{1}{2}}
2:\aermb[1pt]{\dfrac{1}{2}}
3:\aermb[3pt][1pt]{\dfrac{1}{2}}

\end{document}
```

Of course you'll have better ideas about what to do with the arguments.

[image]