# Insert \par in after-code of a titleformat command

Tags: titlesec, paragraphs, parts

I want to get the following output:

[image]

In words:

1. insert a table of contents for the current part (works fine)
2. Be able to put some text before the ToC (doesn't work)

As I understand it, it is partly because the [`\par` is the argument of a non `\long` macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208881/#comment487849_208881), and also because I still type text inside the label.

So how do I get out of the label and type whatever text I want below it?

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {}
  {\centering\huge\bfseries\partname~\thepart}
  {0pt}
  {\centering\huge}
  [Here is the TOC:\par%
  {\normalsize\startcontents[parts]%
  \printcontents[parts]{}{0}[2]{}}
  ]

\begin{document}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{ch one}
\section{sec one}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\endgraf`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {}
  {\centering\huge\bfseries\partname~\thepart}
  {0pt}
  {\centering\huge}
  [{\normalsize \hspace{-\leftskip}Here is the TOC:\endgraf
    \startcontents[parts]%
    \printcontents[parts]{}{0}[2]{}%
  }]

\begin{document}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{ch one}
\section{sec one}
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC]

---

moved from comments:

> In short, how could I know (and how YOU knew) that endgraf is the macro needed in this case? –  tush

answers:

- long time TeX user; `\endgraf` is inherited by LaTeX from the Plain TeX format, but as you discovered it is transmogrified by LaTeX into something very complicated which however is same very complicated LaTeX `\par` in general text.
- I looked now in TeXBook source and for example you see it mentioned in an answer to an exercice `The only tricky part about this answer is the use of\/ ^|\endgraf|, which is a substitute for |\par| because |\loop| is not a ^|\long| macro.` on lines 13530-13531
- other extract `The meaning of\/ |\par| is changed so that it does more than usual: First it does ^|\endgraf|, which is \TeX's ordinary |\par| operation; then it sets...` so you see this `\par`/`\endgraf` business is very familiar to people who first learned how to use TeX and only later LaTeX.
- it was a choice of LaTeX to keep the `\endgraf` but this is not mandated by TeX: it is a construct of Plain TeX which is imitated by other formats.

Comment: `latex.ltx` says `\let\endgraf=\par` but `\show\endgraf` gives a much longer definition. Why?

Comment: `\show\par` will give you the same.  This is due to the "para hooks" added by LaTeX since October 2020 release.  But `\par` is modified by LaTeX list environments and there the sync with `\endgraf` is lost.

Comment: when you do `\let\foo\bar`, then `\show\foo` shows you the full meaning of `\bar` at time of the `\let`.  In Plain TeX,`\par` is a primitive so `texdef endgraf` will show you `\endgraf:<on next line>\par` as it has no meaning like a macro; with LaTeX, the TeX `\par` is saved as `\@@par` and `\par` becomes a macro, especially since "para hooks" have been added, but already earlier inside lists.

Comment: BTW, Why adding `\endgraf` here: `{\centering\huge\endgraf}` (at the end of the `begin-code`) is not helpful?

Comment: I suppose the `\endgraf` is then executed too early, this `\centering\huge` is before `Introduction` (edited) is typeset. To be honest ask someone who actually is willing to read titleformat source code... (I have little experience with package `titlesec` and none with `titletoc`)